# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma para aplicar estilos a un input range?

Tags: html, css

Necesito aplicar estilos a un input de tipo range, pero no encuentro la manera de modificar el thumb (la bolita que mueve el range).

HTML:

```
<input class="drag__bar" type="range" min="0" max="4" name="myRange" id="myRange">
```

CSS:

```
    .drag__bar::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background-color: #a4f3eb;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 8px;
    cursor: grab;
}

.drag__bar::-ms-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
  background: goldenrod;
}
```

No funciona en ningún navegador. Dejo ejemplo de como se debería ver ya con estilos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna recomendación?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pseudoclase que debes utilizar es `::-webkit-slider-thumb` (webkit) y `::moz-range-thumb` (firefox). Te dejo un ejemplo algo básico. Como ves puedes poner los iconos dentro del `thumb` con un background.

```css
.slidecontainer {
  width: 100%;
}

.drag__bar {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
  -webkit-transition: .2s;
  transition: opacity .2s;
}

.drag__bar:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.drag__bar::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #a4f3eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 11px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  background: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/59/59089.svg?token=exp=1614064733~hmac=a6f0cce2214fdb52e7df9eec24006427) #75b4c3;
  background-size: 45%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.drag__bar::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #a4f3eb;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow:0px 0px 11px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.26);
  background: url(https://www.flaticon.com/svg/vstatic/svg/59/59089.svg?token=exp=1614064733~hmac=a6f0cce2214fdb52e7df9eec24006427) #75b4c3;
  background-size: 45%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>
<body>
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="drag__bar" id="myRange">  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```